# Named parameters on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, named-parameters

I have many functions that are created like this one:

```
function _campoForm({ id, tipo, regole, campiPerRiga, css, stile, eventi, parametri, abilitato, traduzione, visibile, modelKey, serverKey }) { ... }
```

If I try to run this code on IE, this errors occurs:

```
identifier expected
```

[image]

How can I resolve this without rewrite the entire code?

Thank you! :D

Comment: `{ id=id, tipo=tipo, regole=regole...}`

Comment: well if the browser does not support it, you either change your code or you transpile it with babel.

Comment: @epascarello I have tried to use babel, but I could not make it work by following the guide on their site.

Comment: Fyi, [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) is not supported in IE

Comment: @Hikari, can you show us which link you refer and what steps you followed to implement that babel. We can try to check it and try to provide suggestion for that, If anything implemented incorrectly.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you. I have follow this steps https://babeljs.io/setup#installation (I have select "in the browser")
then I have add to my HTML head --> <script type="text/babel" src="path/to/js/file.js">
My project is a MVC project.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Here the sample project --> https://ufile.io/12puo

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have use this code and now works but is slower then without the scripts:
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Portale/polyfill.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Portale/PortalScripts.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Portale/PortalMaster.js")"></script>
 and this message is write on console:
You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production

How can I fix this?

Comment: @ Hikari, Please try to precompile the script and again try to make a test to check whether it solves the performnce issue or not. Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions, If needed.